# 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch' error using GO

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW#1 AS
SELECT * FROM rota

go
--view#02 – apresentar os voos programados para cada rota.

CREATE VIEW VIEW#2 AS
SELECT TOP (select COUNT(*) FROM voo) IDrota, IDvoo
FROM voo
ORDER BY IDrota

GO
--view#03 – apresentar os técnicos de apoio para cada um dos voos programados.

CREATE VIEW VIEW#3 AS
SELECT TOP (select COUNT(*) FROM tecnicosVoo) V.IDvoo, TV.IDfuncionario, F.PrimeirosNomes, F.UltimosNomes, F.funçãoTecnico FROM voo V
    JOIN tecnicosVoo TV ON V.IDvoo = TV.IDvoo
    JOIN funcionario F ON TV.IDfuncionario = F.IDfuncionario
    ORDER BY IDvoo

GO
--view#04 – apresentar os voos programados para cada rota e os respetivos aviões associados.

CREATE VIEW VIEW#4 AS
SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voo) R.IDrota, V.IDvoo, A.refAviao, A.modelo AS 'Modelo do avião' FROM voo V
    JOIN rota R ON V.IDrota = R.IDrota
    JOIN aviao A ON V.refAviao = A.refAviao
    ORDER BY R.IDrota

--view#05 - apresentar para um voo a relação de lugares disponiveis

go

CREATE VIEW VIEW#5 AS
SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voo) VO.IDvoo, A.NT_passageiros 'Capacidade do avião', (SELECT count(*) FROM VendaVoo where IDvoo = VO.IDvoo and ocupacao = 1) 'Ocupados',
(select round((100.0 - ((select CAST((SELECT count(*) FROM VendaVoo where IDvoo = VO.IDvoo and ocupacao = 1) AS FLOAT) / CAST(A.NT_passageiros AS FLOAT)) * 100)), 2)) 'Percentagem de lugares disponiveis'
FROM voo VO
    JOIN aviao A ON VO.refAviao = A.refAviao
```

And it is giving me this error:

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure VIEW#4, Line 640 Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure VIEW#4, Line 640
> 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch."

So the query creates the view 1, 2 and 3 but doesnt create the other one's. Someone know why?

Comment: Try adding semicolons to the end of the statements.

Comment: Line 640? Your code doesn't have that many lines.

Comment: Yes it does, this is just a piece of it, line 640 is the comment --view#04

Comment: Adding semicolons doent work either...

Comment: I suspect that what you have given us doesn't replicate the problem.

Comment: Where do you execute the code? SSMS? Other SQL client? In a program of yours?

Comment: Microsoft sql server MS

Comment: Yeah, that's the server I got that. But what's the client?

Comment: On SSMS direclty

Comment: Can you execute the separate view creation statements?

Comment: Yes I can, the views are working fine but I cant create them together

Comment: Also worth noting, that there is no such thing as an ordered view. If you expect those ORDER BY clauses to send back the data in order, that won't work. If you only want the ORDER BY to satisfy the requirements for TOP, that's fine. But it looks like you're trying to select all the rows in order and that won't work.

Comment: And another. Don't declare aliases like this:

'Percentagem de lugares disponiveis'

Instead, declare them like this:

AS [Percentagem de lugares disponiveis]

Comment: Somehow the word 'GO' is being treated as part of the batch rather than a batch separator.   SMSS thinks that GO is not on a line by itself.   For example, if the previous line ends in a backslash, then the GO will be considered part of the previous line.  There's something in your script that you're not showing us.   I imagine that if you copy-and-paste the code you've shown here into SMSS and run it, it will work.    Can you copy-and-paste the code that surrounds the badly-behaved GO and show it to us?